# Gain the Enchantment Property from Both Implements and Weapons?

Tags: dnd-4e, weapons

If we legaly wield two weapons or implements, do we gain the Enchantment property from both?
I've found this on it.

### Player's Handbook p.225

> **Property:**
>   Some magic items have a special property that is constantly
>   active (or active under certain conditions). A
>   property doesn’t normally require any action to use,
>   although some properties allow you to turn them off
>   (or on again).

---

### Update; Adventurer's Vault p.56

> **Weapon Property:** Many weapons have properties that provide a
>   constant benefit. To gain the benefit of a weapon’s
>   property, you must be wielding the weapon. Unless
>   specified otherwise, a property affects only the
>   weapon to which it’s attached. For example, a +2 cunning
>   dagger, which bestows a –2 penalty to an enemy’s
>   saving throws against your weapon powers, affects
>   only powers that are delivered using that weapon.
>   You couldn’t hold the weapon in your off-hand and
>   gain the benefit of the property on powers delivered
>   using a main weapon.

---

### [D&D: FAQ for the Player's Handbook](http://wizards.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1396)

> **Can a Warlock benefit from holding two rods?** 
>   Yes, a warlock can gain the properties from two rods but he still can only use one to make an attack.

---

### Player's Handbook p.239

> **Rods:**
>   If you are a member of a class that can use a rod as
>   an implement, you can apply its enhancement bonus
>   to the attack and damage rolls of any of your powers
>   from that class that have the implement keyword, and
>   you can use a rod’s properties and powers. Members of
>   other classes gain no benefit from wielding a rod.
>   A rod is a short, heavy cylinder, typically covered in
>   mystic runes or inscribed crystals. As with most other
>   implements, you can’t make melee attacks with a rod.

---

From what I can pull of this is that; Though the FAQ specifically mentioned "Warlock", the answer itself was for Implements in general since the entry for "Rod's" in PHB p.239 didn't mention any specific rule regarding this, so it works for Implements.

In PHB the rules on the magical properties was speaking of how a magical item's property functioned in general, as a result you could wield two magical melee weapons and benefit from the property of each, but after AV this hole was filled and this particular quality was granted to "Double Weapon's" at the cost of limiting versatility.

Have I missed something or is there a loophole that can be used?

Comment: +1 for the research, but this could use some more connecting text between all the block quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a power that requires a Weapon or Implement you must choose one to make the attack with and usually, only that item's properties apply to the attack. However, there are items that apply bonuses that benefit attacks even when they are not being used to make them.

For example:

- A Fighter using two weapons with the Two-Weapon Defense feat could use a normal weapon in their Main Hand and a +1 Rhythm Blade
  Dagger in their off-Hand, gaining the benefits of the defense bonuses.
- A Cleric with a mace that had the Weapon of Healing property could hold it in their off-hand and still gain the item's enhancement bonus to healing.
- A Warlock could hold a Rod of Dark Reward in their off-hand to gain the AC bonus whenever they used their Warlock's curse.

Comment: @Andras [Your edit is being discussed in meta.](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3382/1204) In the future, **do not do major edits like this.** Completely changing the message or meaning of a post is not what edits are for. If it's a bad answer, downvote it and post a better one.

Comment: I'm not sure how useful this answer is without some method to tell whether any particular property can apply to an attack made with a different weapon or not.